# String Parsing in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, replace, substring

I'm looking at pulling two numeric values from a single text string in SQL (2012 version i believe).

The strings are in the following possible formats:

```
A1234 B4567
```

or

```
A:1234 B:4567
```

or random variants of

```
A[Symbol/Space/Nothing][Numberstring1] [Space/Nothing] B[Symbol/Space/Nothing][Numberstring2]
```

Ideally I'd use a combo of substring and charindex but because the symbols/space/nothing at all are used at random i'm finding it difficult.
My preferred output would be 2 columns, one with the [NumberString1] one with [Numberstring2]

Any ideas folks?

Comment: Any value to reading all the values into memory and parsing in code? You can parse in SQL but any modern procedural language (Java, C#, JavaScript etc.) has much more powerful parsing support. This looks like a problem that Regular Expressions would be well suited to.

Comment: Ideally I'd push this out onto the .net developers to use a language suited for it but they're swamped and the responsibility has fallen on the Data Analysts. I could push back as it's currently done manually but I do like a puzzle so I'm poking away at it in SQL when I can.

Comment: These are just two fields delimited by `<space>B` right? Split them, remove A and B, remove any non numeric leading characters

Comment: Split was my first go to, unfortunately the space/delimiter isn't always present or the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give this approach a try, it will give you a list of all the number groups. You could then select from the resulting table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ParseOutNumbers](@inputText varchar(1000))
    RETURNS @ParsedValues TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),numVal varchar(1000))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @charIndex INT
    DECLARE @number varchar(1000)
    DECLARE @nextChar varchar(1000)

    SELECT @charIndex = 1
    SELECT @number = ''

    WHILE @charIndex <= LEN(@inputText)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @nextChar = SUBSTRING(@inputText, @charIndex, 1);

        IF ISNUMERIC(@nextChar) = 1
        BEGIN
            SELECT @number = @number + @nextChar
        END

        IF (ISNUMERIC(@nextChar) = 0 OR @charIndex = LEN(@inputText))
        BEGIN
            IF (LEN(@number) > 0)
            BEGIN
                INSERT @ParsedValues(numVal) VALUES(@number)
                SELECT @number = ''
            END
        END

        SELECT @charIndex = @charIndex + 1
     END

RETURN
END

GO

select * from [dbo].[ParseOutNumbers]('A/d11222Bdd:22002    C23002')
select * from [dbo].[ParseOutNumbers]('A:11222 B:22002 C:23002')
select * from [dbo].[ParseOutNumbers]('A112442B22502C3002')
```

Alternate version:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ParseOutNumbersRev2](@inputText varchar(1000))
    RETURNS @ParsedValues TABLE (A varchar(1000), B varchar(1000))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @charIndex INT
    DECLARE @number varchar(1000)
    DECLARE @nextChar varchar(1000)
    DECLARE @valueIndex INT
    SELECT @charIndex = 1
    SELECT @number = ''
    SELECT @valueIndex = 0
    WHILE @charIndex <= LEN(@inputText)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @nextChar = SUBSTRING(@inputText, @charIndex, 1);

        IF ISNUMERIC(@nextChar) = 1
        BEGIN
            SELECT @number = @number + @nextChar
        END

        IF (ISNUMERIC(@nextChar) = 0 OR @charIndex = LEN(@inputText))
        BEGIN
            IF (LEN(@number) > 0)
            BEGIN
                IF (@valueIndex = 0)
                BEGIN
                    INSERT @ParsedValues(A, B) VALUES(@number, null)
                END
                ELSE IF (@valueIndex = 1)
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE @ParsedValues SET B = @number
                END

                SELECT @number = ''
                SELECT @valueIndex = @valueIndex + 1
            END
        END

        SELECT @charIndex = @charIndex + 1
     END

RETURN
END

GO

select * from [dbo].[ParseOutNumbersRev2]('A/d11222Bdd:22002    C23002')
select * from [dbo].[ParseOutNumbersRev2]('A:11222 B:56 C:23002')
select * from [dbo].[ParseOutNumbersRev2]('A112442B22502C3002')
```

Comment: Marvellous Thank You. I'll pass this to our DBA to create and give it a whirl.